# MobileFirst Development Server closed automatically

Tags: websphere-8, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have been running hybrid applications with IBM MobileFirst Studio 6.3. After running the MobileFirst development server from eclipse for a few hours the server is getting stopped automatically.

FYI - we need this server to keep live for us to test the app in QA environment

Here is the log in the mfp console

`[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://ServerName:10080/worklightadmin/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://ServerName:10080/worklightconsole/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://ServerName:10080/worklight-analytics-service/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application WorklightConsole has stopped successfully.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application WorklightAnalytics has stopped successfully.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application _MobileBrowserSimulator has stopped successfully.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application WorklightAnalyticsServices has stopped successfully.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application WorklightServices has stopped successfully.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://ServerName:10080/IBMJMXConnectorREST/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application XXXXX has stopped successfully.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application YYYYY has stopped successfully.
[AUDIT   ] WTRN0105I: The transaction service has shutdown successfully with no transactions requiring recovery.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0036I: The server worklight stopped after 2 days, 9 hours, 1 minutes, 30.31 seconds.`

Comment: I tried running with mfp cli as well - there also it is getting stopped . Not even getting any relevent messages in the log to see why is it getting closed

Answer (score 0):

The IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation Developer Edition is meant for development purposes and not for production. Based on the logs from the server it looks like the WebSphere Application Server "WAS" is shutting down after 2 days of being opened.

Please check the following link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/getstart/c_wl_editions.html in the IBM Knowledge Center for more information about the different editions for IBM MobileFirst Studio.

Comment: 1. Development server is getting stopped sometimes even in one hour time.
2. As I stated earlier, if we needd to setup a QA envoronment, do we need to purchase One of the non-developer MobileFirst Server editions ?

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea to set up a standalone server for QA & Production. The development server in eclipse is only available while eclipse is running, as Yoel said, this is for development/evaluation purposes. You would need to purchase the product to get a standalone server. For help moving from a Development Environment to QA and Production see: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/moving-production/moving-development-environment-stand-alone-qa-production-servers/

Comment: Also, Product Editions info is here: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/getstart/c_wl_editions.html